# indexOff is breaking for specific case in jquery

Tags: jquery, indexof

Concept: I want to add value to a string if it is not exists the string already. i tried to do achieve this by using below code:

```
var liItems = '11,2,4';
if (liItems.indexOf('1') < 0) {
     liItems += '1' + ',';
}
```

in this case i am checking if "**1"** exists in string, but in string we have "**11**" not "**1**".

this case is fails every time. i am not getting how to overcome to this. please help me

Comment: It will be treated as string not integer.

Comment: @JohnR, could you help me how can i achieve this.. with numeric values in string

Comment: Are you aware that "jQuery" is the **NAME OF THE LIBRARY**. Please learn the difference between "javascript" and "jquery".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at below code snippet. You can refer this code for your use:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var liItems = '11,2,4';
  var arr = liItems.split(',');
  
  if (arr.indexOf('1') < 0) {
     arr.push('1');
  }
  
  liItems = arr.join(',');
  
  $("#result").text(liItems);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```